# Mapping land plots which contain two buildings

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I need to show land plots in QGIS that have two buildings.

My query only shows buildings which are placed on land plots.

[image]

```
Create or Replace VIEW dvi_budivli_view AS
Select
"budivly".*,
"dilyanki"
From
public."budivly",
public."dilyanki"
Where
ST_contains ( public."dilyanki".geom, public."budivly".geom);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm presuming "budivly" is your land plots and "dilyanki" is your buildings, and that you have an "id" column as a primary key. I've not tested this, but it should get you started.

EDIT to add option to display count:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dvi_budivli_view AS
SELECT
    budivly.id,
    budivly.geom,
    COUNT(dilyanki.id) -- Optional
FROM
    budivly
JOIN dilyanki
    ON ST_Contains(budivly.geom, dilyanki.geom)
GROUP BY
    budivly.id,
    budivly.geom
HAVING
    COUNT(dilyanki.id) > 1
```

Comment: You don't want to GROUP By  budivly.geom and bidivly.id, as their distinct combination will always be one, and so the having clause will do nothing.

Comment: clarification: HAVING COUNT(dilyanki.id) = 2

Comment: @JohnPowell I just tested the SQL, and it works the same with or without grouping by budivly.geom (only thing that changed was order of parcels). The HAVING refers to the dilyanki.id, not the budivly.id.

Comment: @Cyril You may be correct - it depends on whether the OP considers parcel 1 that has 3 buildings to also contain 2 buildings.